# Jenkins and Tomcat using Reverse-Proxy Auth plugin

Tags: tomcat, plugins, jenkins, basic-authentication, reverse-proxy

I cannot seem to find a good explanation on how to get Jenkins running on a Tomcat server using basic HTTP authentication.

Some basic information:

OS: Windows 7 64 bit
Tomcat version: 7.0.40
Jenkins version: 1.516
Reverse-Proxy Auth Plugin version: 1.0.1
Java SDK version: 1.7.0_17
Java JRE version: 7
Tested with Chrome and IE

I currently have Jenkins up and running successfully on my Tomcat server with the Reverse-Proxy Auth Plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Reverse+Proxy+Auth+Plugin) enabled, a user and role added in `tomcat-users.xml`, and a few lines added to me `web.xml`. Both of which are displayed below. (Both files are located at `C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 7.0/conf/`)

**tomcat-users.xml** (Everything is default except adding of one role and one user)

```
<role rolename="Administrator"/>
<user username="John" password="password" roles="Administrator"/>
```

**web.xml** (everything default except the addition of this section)

```
<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
  <web-resource-name>
    Jenkins
  </web-resource-name>
  <url-pattern>/jenkins/*</url-pattern>
  <http-method>GET</http-method>
    <http-method>POST</http-method>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>Administrator</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<!-- Define the Login Configuration for this Application -->
<login-config>
  <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
</login-config>
```

I am not sure why but whenever I go to `http://localhost:8080` or `http://localhost:8080/jenkins` there is no login prompt, but if I change the `<url-pattern>/jenkins/*</url-pattern>` to `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` I get a login prompt simply by going to `http://localhost:8080`, which is fine. After I log in if I go to /jenkins then I get forwareded to the login page, which is all "messed up" [none of the resources show up and the page looks broken].

This is what it looks like:

[image: Broken Jenkins]

Here is a link that I found that is close to the same issue I am having. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/jenkinsci-users/AVTklGHmzkc

Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT 1**
Added the versions of Java in case that is needed/relevant

**EDIT 2**
Added a picture of what Jenkins looks like when it is "broke"

**UPDATE 1**
Still getting the same issues, have tried different combinations of things in the web.xml file but still getting the same issue.

**UPDATE 2**
No Fix found yet, but I have been doing my best to get around it. I will set the url-pattern to `/*`, log into Tomcat, stop the server, change it back to `/jenkins/*` (which I believe does nothing) and start the server again then go to the Jenkins page to get the authenticated HTTP headers. Still wanting a solution to my problem but have yet to find one...

Comment: I would get rid of tomcat. I had it before and it runs much better as a service without tomcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the problems I was able to spot:

1. You don't need the Reverse Proxy Auth Plugin unless you plan to use Apache or some other web server as a reverse proxy.
2. There should be a

   ```
   <security-role>
     <role-name>Administrator</role-name>
   </security-role>
   ```

   element after the `<login-config>` element
3. `C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 7.0/conf/web.xml` is the configuration for Tomcat's "default" servlet, which is used to serve static assets. Adding a security constraint to this servlet causes all the static assets to become inaccessible, which is causing filling your login screen with dead links.

Instead, add the security constraint to `C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 7.0/webapps/jenkins/WEB-INF/web.xml`

This should just work, but additional changes to `C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 7.0/conf/server.xml` may be needed to configure the realm. See the [Tomcat doc related to this](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html).

Comment: Ok, thank you I am semi-past this at this point though. I have just went with using Jenkins on its own instead of through Tomcat, I had way to many problems with it. Thank you for the answer though, I will give you the answer since I believe it would solve the problem about the missing resources.